# Not able to submit form in chrome through javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome

Form submission is working good on both IE and Firefox, but recently i tested my application on chrome. In that i found chrome is not submitting form, there are no error messages in chrome console, can u help me. i had gone through server answers , still i didn't get proper solution. here is my js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function callModule(){
     document.frmcheckUserDomain.submit();
}

</script>

<form name="frmcheckUserDomain" action="checkUserDomain.do" method="post">

// here is my form fields

 <input type="button" name="subBtn" value="Submit" onClick="callModule();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your callModule method to this...

```
 function callModule(){
     document.getElementById("frmcheckUserDomain").submit();
}
```

Also, you will want to give your form tag an id attribute...

You could also access the form via index as well...

```
 function callModule() {
     document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: The form doesn't have an ID, it has a name.

Answer (score 1):

first of all why don't you use input submit button instead, like:

```
<input type="submit" name="subBtn" value="Submit" />
```

and if you have some stuff to do when the form gets submitted, you can use `onsubmit` event in your form.

And for your solution, you can pass it as an argument and then submit it:

```
<input type="button" name="subBtn" value="Submit" onClick="callModule(this);" />
```

your function:

```
function callModule(elm){
    elm.parentNode.submit();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `this` refer to the input element, not the form?

Answer (score 0):

see, your code is working fine in my Google chrome. i think u have some issues with your browser or better u check the java Servlet configuration.